# How to fix the margins of my grid to make it more responsive?

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see whenever I resize the window, the gap between the horizontally adjacent element is messed up. Is there any way of fixing this?

This is the code that is resposible for the table:

```
main { /* takes care of building the grid
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(589.19px, auto));
    overflow-x: hidden;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.character-card{ /* takes care of the content inside the individual cells
    display: flex;
    margin: 13.5px;
    background-color: rgb(60,62,68);
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(37, 37, 37, 0.5);
}
```

To see the full code here is my codepen:
https://codepen.io/Alessandro-Garcia/pen/RwqNaPq

Comment: This is actually irrelevant to the problem, but why is the GIF so small?

Comment: any bigger and I can't upload the gif

Comment: use counter, not counters : `ol.list-style-1>li:before {
  content: counter(item);
  counter-increment: item;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -30px;
}`

Comment: What exactly are you expecting here? Cause I understand you also don't want the cards to have internal empty spaces?